# Reading ZonedDateTime from hsqldb with hibernate loses TimeZoneInfo

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb, zoneddatetime

I am using a ZonedDateTime to track events happening in the system. E.g.

```
class PurchaseOrder {
    // The rest is skipped
    @Column(name = "created", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE", nullable = false)
    private ZonedDateTime created;
}
```

To run some tests I am using a hsqldb in memory database. I am populating it by running a sql script by specifying it in the configuration .properties file

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files=create-for-test.sql
```

In that file I insert a record as

```
INSERT INTO purchase_order (id, consumer_id, provider_id, created, modified, purchase_order_status_id)
VALUES
(1, 1001, 1, '2017-01-11 11:45:20.523+01:00', NULL , 1);
```

It executes without any issues.

Later, when I fetch this record from the database running a @NamedQuery, I alway end up with a value in a local time zone. The part of the log where reading happens is:

```
Hibernate: select purchaseor0_.id as id1_52_, purchaseor0_.consumer_id as consumer5_52_, purchaseor0_.created as created2_52_,... from purchase_order purchaseor0_ where purchaseor0_.id=?
binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
extracted value ([id1_52_] : [BIGINT]) - [1]
extracted value ([consumer5_52_] : [BIGINT]) - [1001]
extracted value ([created2_52_] : [TIMESTAMP]) - [2017-01-11T11:45:20.523-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]]
```

So: I am inserting it with a TimeZone +01:00 and the Hibernate stack reads it back in the local TimeZone -08:00.

Is there a way to actually read the whole timestamp with a correct zone?

The same code is running in production on Postgres and the timestamps are behaving as expected there (i.e. I can write and read the ZonedDateTime and the zone info does not get lost).

Edit:
@fredt
The Postgress returns Timestamp as well, but 'respects' the timezone specified in the script.

Example:

```
UPDATE product
  SET
    published_from = '2017-01-01 00:00:00.000+01:00',
    published_to = '2017-01-31 00:00:00.000+01:00'
WHERE id = 3312;
```

And the log output:

```
select distinct productimp0_.id as id1_39_, ...
  productimp0_.published_from as publish16_39_, productimp0_.published_to as publish17_39_, ...
from product productimp0_ where productimp0_.id=?


binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [3312]
...
extracted value ([publish16_39_] : [TIMESTAMP]) - [2016-12-31T15:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]]
extracted value ([publish17_39_] : [TIMESTAMP]) - [2017-01-30T15:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]]
```

In the INSERT statement a UTC+01 was used (European time) and the hibernate/driver converted it to a local time (UTC-08). As long as I get the correct point in time, this is fine with me, as internally the complete application is aware of timezones etc.

Comment: Your use case should be using `OffsetDateTime` as you just have offset not a timezone. Try with that and see if it helps.

Comment: What object does the code return from Postgres for the timestamp?

Comment: @Veeram: `OffsetDateTime` produces the same results.

Comment: Is the column type in the database (not the field annotation) actually "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE", or just "TIMESTAMP"?

Comment: @teppic: Yes, for both databases hibernate logs `create table purchase_order (id bigint not null, created TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE not null, ...`